# How to correct the error "can not assign value of type [NSManagedObject] to type [String]

Tags: swift

I have built a small app that uses core data and could send the sms. Now on the sending sms part, it kept telling me the following one "messageVC.recipients = items" has the error " can not assign value of type [NSManagedObject] to type [String]. items is an array of NSManagedObject and store the telephone number. 
I have tried  messageVC.recipients = items.Stringvalue, messageVC.recipients = items as! [String],messageVC.recipients = items.valueforkey["phonenumeb"] as? String, it can not work. Please help.
Thank you very much.

@IBAction func sendCurrentLocSms(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    messageVC.body = "My address is " + "\(myAddress.text!) " + ". " + "My GPS is " + "\(myLat.text!)" + "," + "\(myLong.text!)"


    messageVC.subject = "Attention!"


    messageVC.recipients = items

    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank MirekE and all the other experts, the following code works. I appreciate all your help. Thanks again.

messageVC.recipients = items.map{

```
        return $0.valueForKey("phonenumber") as! String}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get an array of strings first. Depending on your entity and NSManagedObject subclass (if you have any), something like this should work:

```
messageVC.recipients = items.map { $0.phonenumber }
```

Comment: Thank MirekE. I tried to your way. but it said that "value of type NSManagedObject has no member of phonenumber. "My Entity is "Contact", the only attribute is "phonenumber". it is a string var items = [NSManagedObject]() is located in the beginning

Comment: Thank MirekE. Also with the help of other experts,  the following works. messageVC.recipients = items.map{
            
            return $0.valueForKey("phonenumber") as! String}